# How to create a this type of curved list of widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-design, flutter-path

[image]

i'm creating this type of selection widget with curved shape in flutter, i have search so many packages and code snippet but not give a result i need, please let me know anyone how to create a list of widget into curved shape in flutter.

Comment: the easiest way is to convert the tooth layout to svg format, something like this world map: https://gist.github.com/pskink/afd4f20a40ae7756555877ec030daa46

Comment: @pskink its all teeth are clickable in svg format its not possible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.